# IDLE won't start; unexpected unicode characters in file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

I'm running Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7. Recently I became unable to open IDLE directly. When I run Python from the command line and import `idlelib.idle` I get this error:

```
>>> import idlelib.idlepython`.exe
Traceback (Most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\idle.py", line 10, in <module>
    import idlelib.PyShell
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 26, in <module>
    from idlelib.EditorWindow import EditorWindow, fixwordbreaks
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\EditorWindow.py", line 68, in <module>
    class EditorWindow(object):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\EditorWindow.py", line 69, in EditorWindow
    from idlelib.Percolator import Percolator
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\Percolator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from idlelib.WidgetRedirector import WidgetRedirector
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\WidgetRedirector.py", line 109
    root.w↨+
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The arrow character after `root.w` is `U+21a8`. I'd say that file `WidgetRedirector.py` is corrupted probably.

Comment: Make sure the line 109 reads `root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.quit)` in `C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\WidgetRedirector.py`. If not, re-install Python or just IDLE.

Comment: Interesting, I've had something like this happen to me recently but I used Python 3.3.3. I'm not sure if this would be too big of a task for you as you might have to re-download stuff, but what fixed it for me was reinstalling Python.

Comment: @jadkik94 just uninstalled and re-installed python 2.7. IDLE is now working, thanks for the help!

Comment: Do not use screenshots for pure text information. Copy and paste the error text.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I never thought I'd be transcribing error messages... but this would be unGoogleable unless I did.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure the line 109 reads
>
> ```
> root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.quit)
> ```
>
> in `C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\WidgetRedirector.py`.
>
> If not, re-install Python or just IDLE.

From jadkik94, in the comments.